# How to apply State and Country Picklist on a Custom Object after enabling the feature

Tags: picklist, country-and-state

I followed the instructions for enabling the State and Country Picklist from https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/222/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/state_country_picklists_impl_guide.pdf
[image]
And afterwards when creating a new account records from the account objects, I can confirm that the State and Country Picklist functionality is working.

However I am not quite understanding how to access the feature on a custom object. As a test example I'd like to create an object that represents a candidate for a recruiting application but when I create the object and try to add a picklist field to add where the candidate is from, there is no difference in picklist options prior to enabling it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The State and Country picklist feature adds picklists to standard address fields. Unfortunately the address field type is not available for creating new custom fields, so it's not possible to add them to custom objects.

From the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_state_country_picklists_overview.htm&type=5):

> State and country picklists are available in the shipping, billing,
>   mailing, and “other” address fields in the account, campaign members,
>   contact, contract, lead, order, person accounts, quotes, and service
>   contracts standard objects. The picklists are also available for
>   managing users and companies in Setup.

[Here's a popular idea on the IdeaExchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrVWAA0) to upvote and follow for making address into a custom field type.